# Fullcalendar - go to Date from monthView after picking the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Im using Fullcalendar v2.1.1. I want to make action:

1. Jump to agenda day from month view after picking the date.
2. When Iam on agendaDate view and i click on event I get modal.

Here are my tries:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

                self.showEditDateModal(jsEvent.start);
            }
 this.showEditDateModal = function(startdate) {
        self.calendarAvailable.fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
        self.calendarAvailable.fullCalendar('gotoDate', startdate);
    }
```

And here is modal that I want to appear when you click from agendaDay view:

```
 $('#reservationDateModal').modal('show');
```

I found this:[StackLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463509/jquery-full-calendar)
but when I use it that way:

```
self.calendarAvailable.fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2010, 5);
```

I get date: 1 January 1970
I also try (from documentation) to pass there date object but nothing help [FullCallendar docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

Comment: try removing `self` from `self.showEditDateModal(jsEvent.start);`.self can refer to the window object.

Comment: `self.calendarAvailable.fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2010, 5);`.In fullCalendar v2  . `fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )` date can be a Moment object, or anything the Moment constructor accepts

Comment: I found out that when I pass string like: "2015-04-15" it works but what about second part of question (When Iam on agendaDate view and i click on event I get modal.)

Comment: for second part try `eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {$('#reservationDateModal').modal('show');}`

Answer (score 2):

I made it finally:

1. To use '**gotoDate'** you need to pass there string like this:

> self.calendarAvailable.fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2015-04-24');

and to make it automatically:

```
 this.changeViewtoAgendaDay = function(startdate) {
            var goto = startdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            self.calendarAvailable.fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
            self.calendarAvailable.fullCalendar('gotoDate', goto);
        }
```

2. Answer for second point is simple if made for view:

> if(view.name=='agendaDay'){ self.showEditDateModal(); }else{
>   self.changeViewtoAgendaDay(calEvent.start); }

Where:

```
this.showEditDateModal = function() {
        $('#reservationDateModal').modal('show');
    }
```

Comment: will event click will open the modal?

Comment: This if is in event click.